# Delete Accounts restriction still works in unit tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, permissions

The permission to delete Accounts is unchecked in test User Profile according to this trailhead article. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/protect-your-data-in-salesforce/create-new-users-and-delete-accounts
[image]

I checked manually by logging on behalf the user with the profile. The restriction works - delete button is hidden everywhere. No way to delete accounts.

However, I can still delete account in a unit test.

```
@isTest
private with sharing class AccountTest {

@isTest
static void testAccountCRUD () {
    User testUser = TestDataFactory.generateUser('Standard Profile - No Acct Delete', 'Western Sales Team');
    insert testUser;

    Account[] testAccountList = new Account[]{};

    // Create
    System.runAs(testUser) {
        Account testAccount = TestDataFactory.generateAccount();
        testAccountList.add(testAccount);
        insert testAccount;
    }

    // Read
    System.runAs(testUser) {
        Account[] accList = [select Id, OwnerId, Name from Account];
        System.assertEquals(1, accList.size());
    }

    // Delete
    System.runAs(testUser) {
        System.assertEquals(true, Database.delete(testAccountList[0], false).isSuccess());
    }
    
    // Read
    System.runAs(testUser) {
        Account[] accList = [select Id, OwnerId, Name from Account];
        System.assertEquals(0, accList.size()); // account was deleted
    }
}
}
```

Why it is possible to delete accounts in unit tests even if the user doesn't have the permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, Salesforce doesn't perform object-level permission or field level permission checks in Apex.

In order to do that you need to do something like:

```
if (Schema.sObjectType.Account.isDeletable()) {
  System.assertEquals(true, Database.delete(testAccountList[0], false).isSuccess());
}
```

See the documentation about [Enforcing Object and Field Permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm).

Another detail worth pointing out is that `System.runAs` don't respect object or field level permission, being useful for testing sharing rules but not for that (as seen in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm)).